# Tooltip displaying wrong datetime

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a mschart control where I am graphing some points from a datagrid.  After populating my chart I do the following code:

```
foreach (Series s in chart1.Series)
{
    s.ToolTip = "X=#VALX, Y=#VALY";
}
```

This does set the tooltip, but as shown in the screen shot below, when I mouse over the point it has the wrong x value.  Which is weird because the x-axis has the correct values so if you line the interval up with the point you can tell what it is, but for some reason the tooltip is wrong (but the y-value in the tooltip is correct).

[image: MsChart]

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:  I asked this question 6 years ago and now I know a little more about MSCharts.  A couple of things that will cause this;

1. Storing your data as a `String` instead of a `DateTime` format can cause the tooltip to not work properly. (which is what happened here, all my timestamps were being stored as strings.  Don't do this, it's much better to use a Datetime).
2. Make sure your `ChartType` is type `Line` chart and not `FastLine` chart.  Tool tips won't work with FastLines.

Comment: Does it need formatting, such as:  `s.ToolTip = "X=#VALX{M/d/y}, Y=#VALY";`?

Comment: My tooltip stopped showing up completely when I added that formatting.  I tried `s.ToolTip = "X=#VALX{yyyy}, Y=#VALY";` and it set the tooltip value to 1899.  For some reason it really thinks its 1899 but my x-axis is fine, thats what I don't understand.

Comment: Can you tell me which type of chart it is? I need to draw a similar chart.

Comment: I'm using a Line chart using MSCharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code I had the following:

```
        foreach (Series s in chart1.Series)
        {
            s.IsXValueIndexed = false;
            s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        }
```

I removed the s.XValueType from my code and the tooltip started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
chart1.Series[nameseries].ToolTip = "#AXISLABEL";
```

it's work.

Comment: Please clarify your answer.